# power curve fitting with 2 terms

Tags: math, curve-fitting

How can I fit this equation to a set of data (x,y)

```
 y = a x ^ b + c
```

I tried least square error method (in Maple software) and power low but it doesn't work!

Comment: You probably need more than "it doesn't work".

Comment: @robert : I used Maple to solve it by least square error but it can`t solve it analitycaly

Comment: This should go to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

```
Y = a x ^ b  ; Y = y-c
```

so 'a' and 'b' can be obtained from least square method, if 'c' is known. Therefor error can be calculate as a function of 'c'. (only 'c' and not 'a' or 'b')

No I should minimize the square error witch is a function of only 'c'.
It's possible to solve this by a numeric method.